# Biblatex authoryear-icomp doesn't work as expected with polyglossia hebrew support on

Tags: biblatex, polyglossia, hebrew, bidi

I use `biblatex` combined with `polyglossia` Hebrew support:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew} % Line which causes the problem!

\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,natbib=true,backend=biber,mincrossrefs=3,useprefix=false, uniquename=mininit]{biblatex}

\bibliography{bibl}
\begin{document}

Is this true?\footnote{\cite{Bakker}}

\citet{Bakker} gives the following example.

\end{document}
```

The citation in the footnote is correct, but the citation following it in the main text gives an *ibid.* citation. Normally, this should not happen (since the tracking of references should be separate for the main text and footnotes). After some experimentation, I have discovered the culprit for this error is the loading of Hebrew support done by the line `\setotherlanguage{hebrew}`. If I disable it, it works correctly, but it happens that I need Hebrew support. Could anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Mhhh, I would have thought this would work. A MWE would greatly help to investigate this further - without an example there is near-nothing we can do. What I find odd though is that you use `authoryear-comp`, shouldn't you use `authoryear-icomp` for ibidem support?

Comment: Curiously, when I made up an example using the line from above on the spot I got no ibidem at all (as I would have expected) and using `authoryear-icomp` I got the expected behaviour - i.e. citations being tracked separately in the footnote and body.

Comment: I'm afraid without an MWE this question is not really answerable, so if you cannot provide one to make your question more clear I will vote to close.

Comment: You are right, it should have been `authoryear-icomp`. Anyhow, I did some experimentation and discovered the problem has to do with the Hebrew support enabled by the `polyglossia` package. I add an MWE that reproduces the error.

Comment: That might be connected to [this bug](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/157) - I'm not entirely sure, since the bug mentions the `bibi` package and you use `polyglossia`'s `hebrew`, but both have to do with right-to-left typesetting.

Comment: Seems like `polyglossia` (or someone else) loads `bidi` internally.

Comment: You are right. `polyglossia` loads `bidi` for the handling of Hebrew. This is probably the source of the problem, since `bidi` redefines footnotes. Maybe some experts of `bidi` could help...

Comment: That is most definitely it, maybe you want to air your grievances in the [`biblatex` bug-tracker](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/).

Comment: See also [*Patching footnotes fails with polyglossia and Hebrew.* #412 at the `biblatex` bug tracker](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/412)

Comment: David Purton has kindly supplied a patch (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/576), can you check with the development version of `biblatex`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has now been fixed in `biblatex` 3.8. You should now get proper tracking of citations within footnotes for RTL languages. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/576 for details.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Is this true?\footnote{\cite{yoon}}

\textcite{yoon} gives the following example.
\end{document}
```

[image]

For comparison, here is the output with `biblatex` 3.7:

[image]