# Bib conditionally render fields

Tags: biblatex, conditionals, biber, url

How can I get biblatex/biber to only render the URL field if the type of the bib latex citation is `misc`, i.e. `not article`?

Comment: Mendele is used. And: `\usepackage[backend=biber,maxbibnames=6,firstinits=true,arxiv=false,doi=false,citestyle=authoryear-icomp,uniquename=false]{biblatex}`

Comment: You could search for the formatting code in the style file you use and alter what you see there for every other key than `misc` to exclude the URL.

Comment: I am based on https://gitlab.cg.tuwien.ac.at/auzinger/vutinfth which is using `vutinfth` but have no idea where to fine a stile file to configure this.

Comment: The 'best' online entry type is `@online` and not `@misc`. If you use `@online`, you can use the preamble option `url=false` that turns off displaying URLs, but makes an exception for `@online` so that the URL there is always printed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`biblatex` supports source maps that let you edit your library on the fly.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pernottype{misc} % only if type is not misc
      \step[fieldset=url, null] % delete field
    }
  }
}
```

The style takes some getting used to, but the "language" is surprisingly powerful. You basically define lists of steps that are executed for each entry. You can add restrictions like the `\pernottype` above and there is the `final` step option that breaks processing if a condition is fulfilled (or not fulfilled, depending on the condition). The following snippet removes eprint and arXiv entries from the database when a DOI is present

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=doi, final] % stop if doi doesn't exist
      \step[fieldset=archiveprefix, null] % delete field
      \step[fieldset=arxivid, null] % delete field
      \step[fieldset=eprint, null] % delete field
    }
  }
}
```

The whole language is documented in section 4.5.3 of the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)

Comment: You learn something new every day. +1 I never found this (till today).

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this is to redefine the `url+urldate` macro so that it only does something for `@misc` entry types. Try putting this in your preamble:

```
\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \ifentrytype{misc}
    {\usebibmacro{url}%
     \iffieldundef{urlyear}
       {}
       {\setunit*{\addspace}%
        \usebibmacro{urldate}}}
    {}}
```

Comment: Since you supplied the patch that solved https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/342236/35864 would you like to write up a short answer there that the problem is fixed in `biblatex` 3.8?

Answer (score 0):

The files are located in your texmf.

If you don't use a bibliography style, search for a file named `standard.bbx` else for a file named `<your-bib-style>.bbx`.

In it you'll find lines like `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}` or `\RequireBibliographyStyle{<another-style>}` (in which case you should search for those files and do the following with them), inside of those blocks you'll find lines like `\usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}`.

You'll notice that most of the types use this macro (including `article` and `misc`). So you could change the definition of this particular bibmacro to don't print an URL (or to do nothing if you don't want `doi` or `eprint` either).

Then you can copy the definition of `\DeclareBibliographyDrive{misc}` and change it to use another macro instead of `\usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}` which matches the original definition of this.

Applying all of this for `standard.bbx` results in:

```
\documentclass[]{article}


\usepackage[backend=biber,maxbibnames=6,firstinits=true,arxiv=false,doi=false,citestyle=authoryear-icomp,uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{article,
  author = {foo},
  title = {bar},
  journal = {baz},
  year = {2017},
  URL = {www.foo.bar}
}
@misc{misc,
  author = {foo},
  title = {bar},
  year = {2017},
  URL = {www.foo.bar}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{misc}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{howpublished}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{type}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{organization+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url2}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


\newbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url2}{% original definition of doi+eprint+url
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\printfield{doi}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\printfield{doi}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock% I don't know whether this should be removed, too, or not
}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{article}
\cite{misc}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you mean in the current (local) dir or in the system wide tex installation?

Comment: @GeorgHeiler both with the local dir having a higher priority (but chances are, that the system wide installation is storing those files and not your local dir). If you don't use a bibliography style (in your comment you use only a citation style), you should be able to use my code.

Comment: This is a bit overkill. You only have to modify the `url+urldate` macro.

Comment: @DavidPurton maybe, but it shows a general way of modifying bibliography styles. Your answer is code wise better, though, as it's simpler :)